# facebook homepage like pull down div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

after logging on to facebook, there is a downward arrow symbol after home tab. On clicking it shows a div (?) which just appears on the existing content and on another click it disappears.

How can I make  exactly such a thing?

**Edit:**

I followed this [link](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/dropdown-gui/index.html) from TheBlackBenzKid. One thing is clear, on clicking on the button, just 2 divs are toggled.

But AFAIK toggle takes place on mouse click. so the 'click' event should be there in the jquery code.

1) But I didn't find it. where is that?

2)there is some css that makes it possible for the menu to appear on a place without dislocating the existing content there( from the demo this is not visible, but it does happen actually). What is that css code?

Comment: There are so many ways to do these things: http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/dropdown-gui/index.html this is a nice one that already comes with simple clean CSS look and feel.

Comment: i have an edit, please notice  that

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid , I would like to accept ur comment as the answer to my question. what can I do?

Comment: I created it within an answer below. Click TICK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do these things: [thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/dropdown-gui/index.html](http://thefinishedbox.com/files/freebies/dropdown-gui/index.html) this is a nice one that already comes with simple clean CSS look and feel

Answer (score 0):

This is how i wouldve done it, but its a pretty basic solution.

```
div id="arrowid">▼</div> 
<div id="dropdownbox" style="display:none;">Dropdownbox</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#arrowid').click(){ 
$('#dropdownbox').toggle();
});   
});
</script>
```

this one does'nt support outside clicks, it just shows and hides when clicking the arrow. Hope it helps!

Comment: one important thing: when the dropbox will appear, then it cannot consume the space of the serial tabs (find friends, home etc). Otherwise the layout will go messy

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to achieve this effect, if you are using jQuery.

Use it to display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

```
.slideToggle( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

> - duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
> - easing: A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
> - callback: A function to call once the animation is complete.